# tests for defined labels (r@) and infinite passes with Makefile

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, makefile

My question probably has to do with `.aux` files and `\newlabel` therein. Here is what I can describe.

- The way my .PDF builds is via a Makefile; I inserted an MWE to show what happens.
- The situation is that I need do avoid issuing `\label` commands for user's `\item`s in a `\begin{enumerate}` environment whenever they give "`multiply defined`" warnings, e.g.:
- when `\label{itm:i}` is for the first `\item` - using `\roman` (representation of counter `enumi`) - as well as for the ninth - using `\alph`; and
- I employ the use of all five (`\alph`, `\Alph`, `\roman`, `\Roman`, `\arabic`) for each `\item`: this `TeX`nique happens [recursively,] iteratively, automatically.
- (My problem is with infinite passes through **`make`**: I explain how.)
- I use the pairs `\ifcsname r@#1\endcsname` in some `\newcommandx`
  that generates `\label`s - or `\@ifundefined{r@#1}{}{}` -, where `#1` would be the label.

The MWE is the following.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{paralist,alphalph,xargs}

\def\alph#1{\alphalph{\value{#1}}}
\def\Alph#1{\AlphAlph{\value{#1}}}

\makeatletter

\newcommandx\mwelabel[3][2=itm,3=r@]{%
\@ifundefined{#3#2:#1}{\label{#2:#1}}{%
\typeout{avoided #2:#1}}}

\newcommandx\MweLabel[3][2=itm,3=r@]{%
\ifcsname#3#2:#1\endcsname%
\typeout{skipped #2:#1}\else%
\label{#2:#1}\fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{MWE}\mwelabel{one}[sec]

TEXT

\subsection{Mwe} \MweLabel{one}[sec]

Text

\section{Mwe} \MweLabel{two}[sec]

See subsection \ref{sec:one}.

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\setcounter{enumi}{24}
\item twenty-five \mwelabel{tst:one}
\item twenty-six \mwelabel{tst:two}
\item twenty-seven
\end{enumerate}

text

\begin{enumerate}[(A)]
\setcounter{enumi}{29}
\item thirty \MweLabel{tst:one}
\item thirty-one \MweLabel{tst:two}
\item thirty-two
\end{enumerate}

See items \ref{itm:tst:one} and \ref{itm:tst:two}.

\end{document}

\endinput

avoided sec:one
skipped sec:one
skipped sec:two
avoided itm:tst:one
avoided itm:tst:two
skipped itm:tst:one
skipped itm:tst:two
```

When I run the command line "`pdflatex mwe.tex ; pdflatex mwe.tex`", after the second pass it `typeout`s what is after `\endinput`.

- When I run `pdflatex` through, instead, the command line "`make clobber clean && make`", the process goes into an infinite loop.

The `Makefile` is the following.

```
# A Makefile for building TeX documents
#

DOC = mwe
TARGETS = $(DOC).pdf
#QUIET = >/dev/null

##  commondefs  ###############################################################
#

-include commondefs
#

MDIRT = *~ core *.stamp _*.* tmp.inputs
LDIRT = *.aux* *.log*
DIRT = $(MDIRT) $(LDIRT)
RM = rm -f

.SUFFIXES: .tex .aux .stamp .pdf

SEP=:
#SEP=\;         # for MikTeX+Cygwin
PDFLATEX = TEXINPUTS=.$(SEP) pdflatex $(QUIET) -shell-escape #-halt-on-error

##  Makefile  #################################################################
#
###############################################################################

.DEFAULT: all
.PHONY: all
.SECONDARY: $(filter-out $(TARGETS), $(DOC).pdf)

all: $(TARGETS)

FDIRT = mwe.pdf

TEXS = *.tex
DEPS = $(DOC).stamp

$(DOC).pdf: $(TEXS) $(DEPS)

#
###############################################################################


##  commonrules  ##############################################################
#

-include commonrules

# Some basic recursive rules for building, installing, and cleaning up
# a source tree
#
subdirs:
    @sub="$(SUBDIRS)"; \
    for i in $$sub; do if test -n "$$i"; then \
          (cd $$i; make); \
    fi; done;

clean: localclean
    @sub="$(SUBDIRS)"; \
    for i in $$sub; do if test -n "$$i"; then \
          (cd $$i; make $@); \
    fi; done;

localclean:
    $(RM) $(DIRT)

clobber: localclean
    @sub="$(SUBDIRS)"; \
    for i in $$sub; do if test -n "$$i"; then \
          (cd $$i; make $@); \
    fi; done;
    $(RM) $(TARGETS)
    $(RM) -r auto


# Rules for TeX files
#
# The line that runs LATEX needs to run inside a subshell to turn off
# "make"'s status checking. It blows away .aux because the .aux file
# created is bad and also breaks biblatex. It touches .stamp to force a
# rebuild.
.tex.pdf:
    @if test -r "$*.aux"; \
       then cp $*.aux $*.auxprev; \
       else echo > $*.auxprev; \
    fi
    @echo "$(PDFLATEX) $<"
    @sh -c "$(PDFLATEX) $< || (rm -f $*.aux; sleep 1; touch $*.stamp; exit 1)"
    @-cmp -s $*.aux $*.auxprev; \
    if test $$? = 1; \
    then \
        #diff -urN $*.aux $*.auxprev; \
        sleep 1; \
        echo "==> Rebuilding $@"; \
        touch $*.stamp; \
        $(MAKE) $@; \
    else \
        echo "==> No need to rebuild $@"; \
    fi
    @rm -f $*.auxprev

.tex.stamp: # backward compatibility
    touch $@
```

- I tried defining separate commands associated with each `\label` using some unused prefix instead of `r@`, i.e., `mwe@`. With `make` there are no longer infinite passes. However, this does not work either, since in both cases there are `multiply defined` warnings from `LaTeX`, that obviously should not be, because the `\label` is to be guarded by `\@ifundefined` or `\ifcsname\endcsname`.

The modified MWE is the following (identical, except `3=mwe@` instead of `3=r@`).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{paralist,alphalph,xargs}

\def\alph#1{\alphalph{\value{#1}}}
\def\Alph#1{\AlphAlph{\value{#1}}}

\makeatletter

\newcommandx\mwelabel[3][2=itm,3=mwe@]{%
\@ifundefined{#3#2:#1}{\@namedef{#3#2:#1}{}\label{#2:#1}}{%
\typeout{avoided #2:#1}}}

\newcommandx\MweLabel[3][2=itm,3=mwe@]{%
\ifcsname#3#2:#1\endcsname%
\typeout{skipped #2:#1}\else%
\@namedef{#3#2:#1}{}\label{#2:#1}\fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{MWE}\mwelabel{one}[sec]

TEXT

\subsection{Mwe} \MweLabel{one}[sec]

Text

\section{Mwe} \MweLabel{two}[sec]

See subsection \ref{sec:one}.

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\setcounter{enumi}{24}
\item twenty-five \mwelabel{tst:one}
\item twenty-six \mwelabel{tst:two}
\item twenty-seven
\end{enumerate}

text

\begin{enumerate}[(A)]
\setcounter{enumi}{29}
\item thirty \MweLabel{tst:one}
\item thirty-one \MweLabel{tst:two}
\item thirty-two
\end{enumerate}

See items \ref{itm:tst:one} and \ref{itm:tst:two}.

\end{document}

\endinput

skipped sec:one
```

How can I really guard reissuing `\label` commands? The "enumerate-item-alph...arabic" context could probably be ignored. I have thus also inserted test cases for `\label`ing `\section`s.

Appreciate all help. Thank s.

- `Makefile` uses tabs in rules! I have put a **`diff`** command in the "`.tex.pdf`" suffix rule, between the `mwe.aux` and `mwe.auxprev` files, whose comparison (the **`cmp`** command) seems to be the criterion to rerun **`$(MAKE)`**. The output of **`diff`** is always the same, only switching between minus and plus on the same lines.

Either:

```
--- mwe.aux 2013-05-30 16:46:01.080584663 +0300
+++ mwe.auxprev 2013-05-30 16:46:00.920586664 +0300
@@ -1,4 +1,10 @@
 \relax 
 \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}MWE}{1}}
+\newlabel{sec:one}{{1}{1}}
 \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Mwe}{1}}
 \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Mwe}{1}}
+\newlabel{sec:two}{{2}{1}}
+\newlabel{itm:tst:one}{{y}{1}}
+\newlabel{itm:tst:two}{{z}{1}}
+\newlabel{itm:tst:one}{{AD}{1}}
+\newlabel{itm:tst:two}{{AE}{1}}
```

or:

```
--- mwe.aux 2013-05-30 16:46:01.595578225 +0300
+++ mwe.auxprev 2013-05-30 16:46:01.439580175 +0300
@@ -1,10 +1,4 @@
 \relax 
 \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}MWE}{1}}
-\newlabel{sec:one}{{1}{1}}
 \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Mwe}{1}}
 \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Mwe}{1}}
-\newlabel{sec:two}{{2}{1}}
-\newlabel{itm:tst:one}{{y}{1}}
-\newlabel{itm:tst:two}{{z}{1}}
-\newlabel{itm:tst:one}{{AD}{1}}
-\newlabel{itm:tst:two}{{AE}{1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can guard reissuing the same command. But you should not use the internal behaviour of `\label` as all labels of the last run are defined at `\begin{document}` when your .aux file is read.

```
\makeatletter

\newcommandx\mwelabel[3][2=itm,3=myr@]{%
  \@ifundefined{#3#2:#1}{%
    \label{#2:#1}%
    \expandafter\def\csname #3#2:#1\endcsname{something}%
  }{%
    \typeout{avoided #2:#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommandx\MweLabel[3][2=itm,3=r@]{%
  \ifcsname#3#2:#1\endcsname%
    \typeout{skipped #2:#1}%
  \else%
    \label{#2:#1}%
    \expandafter\def\csname #3#2:#1\endcsname{something}%
  \fi
}

\makeatother
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! Thanks for your answer, especially reminding me about ".aux only preamble" thing. It seems your reply is just my second MWE, and it would thus be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Following the `\newlabel` track, I could **really** do the correct thing. I redefined `\@newl@bel#1#2#3` so that it splits labels like `itm:tst:one` into `itm` and `tst:one` (or else resorts to the original `LaTeX` definition), tests for `itm` (not to be, e.g., `sec`) and then cancels invocation of the original `LaTeX` definition in cases when my automated mechanism (confused by `\[aA]lph/[rR]oman` thing) led to `multiply defined` `LaTeX` warnings; or otherwise resorts again to the original `LaTeX` definition. Thanks again for your suggestions.